# Which path should I mount for wordpress in docker

Tags: docker, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress. I'm trying to get it running in a docker stack.

I want to mount a named volume like so

`-v wordpress_data:FOO`

But I'm unsure what to use for `FOO` as I don't understand how wordpress stores its data.

What is the difference between `/var/www/html/` and `/var/www/html/wp-content/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running the official [wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) image from dockerhub, the docs advise mapping a volume to `/var/www/html` inside the container.

So your flag would look like:

```
-v wordpress_data:/var/www/html
```

> What is the difference between `/var/www/html/` and `/var/www/html/wp-content/`?

`wp-content` is just a subdirectory of the wordpress installation, which is created on first run.  A number of other files can be found alongside it in this directory:

```
# ls /var/www/html
index.php    wp-blog-header.php    wp-includes    wp-settings.php
license.txt  wp-comments-post.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-signup.php
readme.html  wp-config-sample.php  wp-load.php    wp-trackback.php
wp-activate.php  wp-content        wp-login.php   xmlrpc.php
wp-admin     wp-cron.php           wp-mail.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Though I know it's a subdirectory :-) My point is what is the difference between them? Which should be backed up for example? Which is ephemeral and can be ignored... Where does the config live, etc. I don't know the difference between them, but I've seen enough docker config examples to realise there is an important distiction between them, I just don't know what it is

Comment: I've found it hard to find a definitive source on this.  `wp-content` should be persisted, as it contains themes, plugins & user uploads.  There is a [discussion](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/156) relating to this which advises persisting only `wp-content`, so that the remainder of the files will be updated when an updated image is pulled.  It sounds like the config file `wp-config.php` is built by env vars which are documented on the dockerhub site, so I don't *think* you'd need to back this up.  Probably worth testing this yourself though.